# Pyparsing recursive type definition in DSL

Tags: python, parsing, dsl, pyparsing

I am parsing a domain specific language which has several type definitions. Primitive types have been relatively straight-forward to parse, but moving on to the complex types in the DSL have proven more challenging. I am looking for a strategy to recursively match a definition that can contain a reference to itself.

For example, the map data type can look like this at a high level:

```
map<primitive_type, complex_type>
```

Which can appear in the input as a recursive definition:

```
map<string, map<int, map<string, ...>>>=
```

This map of maps can theoretically be of arbitrary depth.

To make matters more complicated, these nested complex types could also be other complex types as well.

```
map<string, map<int, map<string, array<array<string>>>>>
```

I'm looking for a strategy to handle parsing this so that I get an accurate type containing the nested map type parsed out. I considered just using a regex, but this doesn't feel optimal to me. I also know there exists Forward for recursive grammars, but I haven't quite been able to figure out how to apply it to this scenario. If there are any good patterns or references for this type of parsing I would really appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward is the way to do this.  Since type declarations may themselves contain type declarations, this is probably a good choice for where the Forward will go:

```
import pyparsing as pp
type_decl = pp.Forward()
```

Looking at your examples, I can see we will need some punctuation, we can define some suppressed expressions for these so that they parse, but won't junk up the parsed results:

```
LANGLE, RANGLE, COMMA = map(pp.Suppress, "<>,")

# if we get an ellipsis, we want to keep it, so use Literal instead of Suppress
ELLIPSIS = pp.Literal("...")
```

Next we can do the simple types:

```
simple_type = pp.oneOf("string int float", asKeyword=True)
```

Now the two complex types, `map` and `array`. For these, we will use the Forward wherever a complex type might occur:

```
MAP, ARRAY = map(pp.Keyword, ["map", "array"])
map_type = MAP - LANGLE + pp.Group(simple_type + COMMA + (type_decl | ELLIPSIS)) + RANGLE
array_type = ARRAY - LANGLE + type_decl + RANGLE
complex_type = pp.Group(map_type | array_type)
```

I use the '-' operator here since, if there is a syntax error after seeing a valid "map" or "array" keyword, pyparsing will give us the error within that expression.

At this point we have our complex and simple types, so we can "inject" them into the previously-defined Forward, using the `<<=` operator:

```
type_decl <<= (complex_type | simple_type)
```

Check using `runTests`:

```
type_decl.runTests("""\
    string
    int
    float
    map<string, map<int, map<string, ...>>>
    map<string, map<int, map<string, array<array<string>>>>>
    """, fullDump=False)
```

Gives:

```
string
['string']

int
['int']

float
['float']

map<string, map<int, map<string, ...>>>
[['map', ['string', ['map', ['int', ['map', ['string', '...']]]]]]]

map<string, map<int, map<string, array<array<string>>>>>
[['map', ['string', ['map', ['int', ['map', ['string', ['array', ['array', 'string']]]]]]]]]
```

Comment: Ideally, I should have started by writing out a BNF, which I always STRONGLY encourage. I probably also would have been more explicit in breaking out the valid map key_type and map value_type, and then declared `map_type` as `MAP + LANGLE - map_key_type + COMMA + map_value_type + RANGLE`, since '...' seems to be a special type for a map value type, but not used anywhere else.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, and to call this out for any future readers: '...' is not a literal value that can be encountered. I used this in my example just to reference the fact that the maps can keep going deeper and deeper in the complex section of the map type definition. The ... was just to illustrate the recursion itself in my example. I should probably make an edit to make that clear.

Comment: Go ahead and leave it in - it is your DSL after all so you can put in it whatever you want, and it shows how to address a special case for a type that is used in maps but nowhere else (plus if you change the question, I'll have to change my answer, and I am in lazy mode today).